# CAS Access Token Not Supported in 6.5.2

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token, cas

I am using CAS-Server as my oAuth server and did all the configuration as mentioned in the documentation.

But when I try to hit the postman for generating accessToken I am getting the below exception.

2022-04-28 22:11:58,625 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.web.endpoints.OAuth20AccessTokenEndpointController] - 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Access token request is not supported
at org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.web.endpoints.OAuth20AccessTokenEndpointController.lambda$verifyAccessTokenRequest$2(OAuth20AccessTokenEndpointController.java:187) ~[cas-server-support-oauth-core-api-6.5.3.jar!/:6.5.3]

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when I hit 'POST /oidc/accessToken' without passing correct parameters. It works after I pass correct parameters. Try this:
[Parameters for /oidc/accessToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q4Ud.png)